# Django send new sessionId Cookie even though previous session cookie is not expired

Tags: django, session, cookies

On page load , I look at the (Firefox) developer console, in the network cookie tab. 
I see Django is correctly creating a new session with expires date two weeks ahead.

Refreshing the /admin/login/?next=/admin/ page a few times, 
I see Django send another sessionId cookie (after less than a minute)

Basically the problem I am seeing is that the admin user get logged out after a few refreshing

What can cause that?

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the login page with credentials is going to cause Django to login again, which results in new session credentials.  If you were refreshing a different page (not a login page) you would not expect to get updated credentials.

Comment: no, after i complete login, refreshing the /admin page 10 times would cause it to log out. also inside the login page, it is not sending new session cookie on each refresh